# python request get status code 200 but response.content is empty

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get [this](https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/notation.html) website information by python requests, after clicking the drawing button (red button), the browser will receive 3 responses, for example:

1. [GET] https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/searchid.html?Stock=2330
2. [GET] https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/Stock_api/Notation_cal?Stock=2330&Odate=2022-04-11&Period=3.5&is_log=0&is_adjclose=0
3. [GET] https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/stock_api/Big_Trend?Stock=2330&Odate=2022-04-11&Period=3.5

And I found that first response will set cookie by {'ci_session': 'random string'},
then used the session with cookie to get second and third responses.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36','x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',}
session = requests.session()
url ="https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/searchid.html?Stock=2330"
response = session.get(url, headers = headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')))
```

By this way, I can get success response and then I checked session.cookies.get_dict()
it showed that there is a new cookie {'ci_session': 'random string'}.
So I use same session to get second url's response, here is my code:

```
url2 = "https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/Stock_api/Notation_cal?Stock=2330&Odate=2022-04-11&Period=3.5&is_log=0&is_adjclose=0"
response = session.get(url2, headers = headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.content)
```

I am pretty sure that this session's cookie already has new item "ci_session" ,
the status_code is always 200 but response.content is empty(b'')!
It confused me a lot! Is there any suggest?
Thanks!

Comment: https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/Stock_api/Notation_cal?Stock=2330&Odate=2022-04-11&Period=3.5&is_log=0&is_adjclose=0 is not returning any response json i.e.the content is empty

Comment: I have tried to print response.text, but it's still empty, is there any other way to get the response?

Comment: if i visit this url in the browser: url2 = "https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/Stock_api/Notation_cal?Stock=2330&Odate=2022-04-11&Period=3.5&is_log=0&is_adjclose=0" there is no content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the request from the browser and then i got the api to return data:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'ci_session': 'kndj0o4bbor8a6fh8kafqunk3b',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'invest.wessiorfinance.com',
    'accept': 'text/plain, */*; q=0.01',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.7,no;q=0.6,sv;q=0.5',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    # 'cookie': 'ci_session=kndj0o4bbor8a6fh8kafqunk3b',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer': 'https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/notation.html',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

params = {
    'Stock': '2330',
    'Odate': '2022-04-11',
    'Period': '3.5',
}

response = requests.get('https://invest.wessiorfinance.com/stock_api/Big_Trend', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)
```

Comment: oh! it works, so the problem is my header is not complete, thank you so much!

Comment: For those who need this, to get the request from Chrome, open the URL you want in the browser. Press `Ctrl + Shift + I` and move to the Networks tap. Refresh the page in browser and then in the time diagram above the Network tap, click on the starting moments to get the very first request. Right click on the request and copy with one of the formats available.